# SnakeYaml - How to convert a yaml to list of pojos with `TypeDescription` configuration set?

Tags: groovy, snakeyaml

I have a simple YAML data like this that I'm trying to convert to a POJO object called `Person` using SnakeYaml.

```
age: 123
name: Jackson
phone:
  number: 123456
```

Here is the Groovy code that does it.

```
@ToString
class Person{
    def name
    def age
    Tel phone
}

@ToString
class Tel{
    def number
}

Constructor c = new Constructor(Person.class);
TypeDescription t = new TypeDescription(Person.class);
t.putListPropertyType("phone", Tel.class);
c.addTypeDescription(t);

def person = new Yaml(c).load(input)
println person
```

This creates the `Person` object as expected with `Tel` inside it.

However, when I try to pass a list of `Person` in yaml as follows, I'm getting an error.

```
- age: 123
  name: Jackson
  phone:
    number: 123456
- age: 234
  name: Jackson
  phone:
    number: 123456
```

Here is the error I get

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: No suitable constructor with 2 arguments found     for class soapunit.Person
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructSequence.construct(Constructor.java:587)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:340)
... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I added explicit separator in the yaml content to make it work.

```
---
age: 123
name: Jackson
phone:
  number: 123456
---
age: 234
name: Jackson
phone:
  number: 123456
```

Comment: well this fixes your problem, but does not answer the original question.  so the problem is there for lists?

Comment: @cfrick: Indeed,  see my answer

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @cfrick, the error that you have in your example is that you are defining a *list property*, because you say this:

```
t.putListPropertyType("phone", Tel.class);
```

but in your *Person* class you define a *single* telephone:

```
class Person{
    def name
    def age
    Tel phone //<-- A SINGLE TELEPHONE!!!
}
```

To properly correct this, simply modify your *Person* class to:

```
class Person{
    def name
    def age
    List<Tel> phone //<-- A REAL LIST OF TELEPHONES!!!
}
```